# React/Jest: mocking functions from React components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm learning to write tests and I'm having trouble mocking a function that comes from my component. Some code removed for brevity. By default, `Banner` will render 4 `BannerItem`'s. But in my test, I want to test rendering only one `BannerItem`. I've been referencing other examples to try and mock my function, but can't seem to troubleshoot it.

```
const renderSlides = (numberOfSlides, activeSlide) => (
    range(1, numberOfSlides + 1).map((slide, i) => (
        <BannerItem
            key={i}
            index={i}
        />
    ))
);

class Banner extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activeSlide: 1 };
    }

    setBannerState(state) {
        this.setState({ activeSlide: state });
    }

    render() {
        const numberOfSlides = 4;
        return (
            <div>
                {renderSlides(numberOfSlides, this.state.activeSlide)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { PureBanner } from '../../../../src/modules/banners/Banner';

describe('<Banner />', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();

    let component;

    it('render banner with one item', () => {
        component = shallow(<PureBanner {...props} />);
        component.instance().renderSlides = jest.fn();
        component.update();
        component.instance().renderSlides(1, component.state().activeSlide);
        expect(component.find('BannerItem')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `jest.fn()` mock implementation. Right now it's not doing anything.

So, you could update your test to something like,

```
component.instance().renderSlides = jest.fn(() => [<BannerItem/>]);
```

See the examples [in the documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-implementations).

Be careful about over-mocking; I would encourage you to leave that method as-is and find a way to verify the results w/o mocking, if possible